# Can't understand sum of sum expression

Tags: matrices, summation

I am studying a math lesson where we want to demonstrate that, given three matrices A, B and C, (AB)C = A(BC).
Here is a part of the lesson that expresses the (AB)C matrix in function of i and j :
￼[image]

While I do understand the first line, I don't get at all the meaning of the second one !
Why are we doing the sum of sums here ?
For the first line, that was easy, k corresponds to the row of (AB) and to the column of C.
In the second line, I don't understand what k and l correspond to... more precisely, I don't understand why we have two sums, and why l and k are used at those places.
**To be clear : I don't understand anything in the second line.**

Could you help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate that $(AB)C\neq A(BC)$, you'll have a hard time doing it, because $(AB)C=A(BC)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I am SO sorry ! Corrected my question.

Comment: The sum over $l$ is just the matrix multiplikation of $A$ and $B$ written in components. Just like in the first line where the matrix multiplikation of $A\cdot B$ and $C$ is expressed in components. If you understand the first one the second should be nothing new.

Comment: @M.J.Steil I am trying to understand... what is p, and what is m ?

Comment: Those bounds have to do with the matrix dimensions: so $p$ as you got correctly is the length/dimension of the row of $A\cdot B$ or of the colum of $C$. $m$ is related to the dimensions of $A$ and $B$: to be specific the length of $A$'s rows or $B$'s columns. And you need the two sums becaus you have two matrix multiplikations in play here.

Answer (score 1):

The new sum is definition of the $i,k$ entry of $AB$.